Is there any way to render a large Jupyter notebook of about 200MB on NBviewer?
Is there any way that I can render a Jupyter notebook of about 200MB on NBviewer? This does not work via Github due to Github's maximum size of 25MB for Jupiter notebooks (that's without storing them in Github LFS).
I understand that there are other platforms with which I can render a 200MB Jupyter Notebook, but I would love to know if this is possible with NBviewer. Thanks.
I tried uploading the Jupyter notebook to Google collab, and then saving as Github gist, but this did not work as no new gist was created in Github.

You can point nbviewer at any URL and so I think you can test it without needing to install it yourself. The form at https://nbviewer.org/ lists several options before you start entering text in it. But it says here at it's GitHub page, "Run this locally to get most of the features of nbviewer on your own network" and so maybe you need to have it local to open something that big? This issue discusses things.

Thanks for your comment @Wayne, I'm still stuck on this unfortunately. I have tried hosting the notebook on HuggingFace, and a link was generated for which I could have it rendered on nbviewer. I tried opening the link but it loads for sometime and gives me a 503 error.                                                                                                        I have also installed nbviewer locally, but still having the same exact problem as above.

"I have tried hosting the notebook on HuggingFace" I didn't know HuggingFace hosted static content. Does your local install of nbviewer work with smaller notebooks? If so, I think you have fully tested the abilities of nbviewer and answered your own post. There's a lot of things that Jupyter .ipynb files are good for; however, you seem to have found one of the several things they aren't meant to do. If you search "why i hate jupyter notebooks" in your favorite search engine, you'll get additional ways they aren't the solution to everything computational-wise. As for your goal, here ...

 are you interested in having something in a large report document? This gets away from your title but maybe that is why you ended up trying this? (This makes it an XY problem, if so.) You could have a Jupyter Notebook where you run all the code but the isn't stored in the actual notebook and instead you make a separate document like a PDF or other form. There's many ways to do this. Some tools to in this are here, but since ...

 it is pretty open-ended there's a lot of ways to do this and so if you had some specifics to share, that would help.

Hi @Wayne.  To be specific, I have a Jupyter notebook that contains interactive Plotly maps, and I would like to render the notebook (such that the maps would still be interactive) and generate a sharable link for it which I will include in my blog post. Also, I do not want to go for collaborative platforms like Google colab, JuyterLab, Binder because I do not want viewers to be able to run the code. All I want is for viewers to see the code cells and their outputs, and the interactive Plotly maps.

Plotly code should remain interactive as 'static' rendering, and so I can see why you don't want them to run the code. However, you can put each plot map in a different notebook and still link to it in your blog post. You should actually be able to embed it (or some of them) in your blog because they can work embedded. However, if you need them as one notebook file than JupyterLite may be your only alternative since nbviewer is limited in size it can render without an active kernel. I wonder though if JupyterLite may have a problem with such big .ipynb files.

Hi @Wayne. Thanks for suggesting JupiterLite. I do need everything as one notebook file. I successfully uploaded the notebook to JupiterLite, however the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to generate a shareable link for it. After reading from their official documentation here, I've done as stated but the link copied doesn't point to any notebook but only just creates a new instance of JupyterLite. Please do you have any idea how I could get a shareable link for a notebook from JupiterLite?

Opening the copied link opens a new JupyterLite tab, showing a "File Load Error" followed by an "Invalid Response: 404". I've also tried this with notebooks smaller than 25MB, and this is still the case. The "Shareable Link" doesn't open up the notebooks, just same error.

The shareable link is to launch a notebook that is hosted on that JupyterLite site, I think. You should get a new session because the shareable link will open a specified notebook in the new session on the new user's computer running inside their browser. You would need to set up your own deployment and turn on real-time collaboration to share the actual notebook, I think. I don't know if that all works yet, see here. I don't think it is enabled on the main JupyterLite page, but you can try and see. It's cutting edge.
